# Cannot add new widget instance in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, widget

I have a website that I set up in Magento 1.9.0 and recently I was trying to add a new widget instance and discovered it would not let me.  My intent is to reference a static block which I successfully added.  When I go to add the new widget instance it lets me pick the Type: (cms static block) and Design Package/Theme from the drop down and then it flashes a message near the top that says "!Widget Instance not full complete to create" but then it's gone.

When I go to give it a name and save it I am not allowed to complete the process and the "Frontend Properties" tab has a yellow triangle appear that says "This tab contains invalid data please solve the problem before saving."  It lets me pick the block from the widget options without additional errors but I cannot save it to complete the process.  I should also note that the two drop downs for Type and Design Package/Theme become grayed out after selecting them and become unresponsive.

I am using the rwd theme provided by Magento but I don't think that matters because I have tried switching to the default theme and no matter what selections I make from the drop downs (I tried many combinations) the result is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Which widget are you trying to add? Is this a widget you are developing yourself?

The "Widget Instance not full complete to create" message seems benign, and appears to be due to the form having to be completed in two stages - the first to select the template, the latter to choose views and add layout updates. I wouldn't worry about that.

Expect the issue here is that the "Widget Options" section (see right hand sidebar) has required options which need to be filled in before you can save the instance. If it's a widget you're developing yourself, there may be problems in the parameters in the widget.xml file, so would maybe help if you could paste that here in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> Widget instance is not full complete to create.

This error message is caused by a Magento 1.x bug.

### Explanation

When this happens, after selecting Type and Theme/Package, there are two requests done:

1. `http://www.domain.dev/index.php/admin/widget_instance/validate/?isAjax=true` and with the following posted Form Data:

   form_key:4izvVF4VrYgxs6W3
   type:yourmodule/yourwidgettype
   package_theme:rwd/default
2. `http://www.domain.dev/index.php/admin/widget_instance/edit/type/{{type}}/package/{{package}}/theme/{{theme}}/`

Checking what happens: 
1st request calls `\Mage_Widget_Adminhtml_Widget_InstanceController::validateAction()`
which will do `$widgetInstance = $this->_initWidgetInstance()` then `$widgetInstance->validate()`;
`_initWidgetInstance()` will do:

```
$instanceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('instance_id', null);
$type       = $this->getRequest()->getParam('type', null);
$package    = $this->getRequest()->getParam('package', null);
$theme      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('theme', null);
```

Problem here is that there are no two parameters package and theme, but one named package_theme, which should have been split to find out the two needed. **This is the bug.**

But why we think sometimes this does not happen?
Let's check how the requests are launched:

The Continue button has `onClick="setSettings('http://www.domain.dev/index.php/admin/widget_instance/edit/type/{{type}}/package/{{package}}/theme/{{theme}}/', 'type', 'package_theme')"`
The function called is:

```
function setSettings(urlTemplate, typeElement, packageThemeElement) {
    if (!editForm.validate()) {
        return false;
    }

    typeElement = $F(typeElement).replace(/\//g, '-');
    packageThemeElement = $F(packageThemeElement).split(/\//g);

    setLocation(new Template(urlTemplate, /(^|.|\r|\n)({{(\w+)}})/).evaluate({
        'type':    typeElement,
        'package': packageThemeElement[0],
        'theme':   packageThemeElement[1]
    }));
}
```

Looking at the second part, we can see the split is done and url looks correct:

```
/index.php/admin/widget_instance/edit/type/yourmodule-yourwidget/package/rwd/theme/default/
```

But first, there is the `editForm.validate()` part which somehow ajax calls the `validateAction()` from `\Mage_Widget_Adminhtml_Widget_InstanceController::validateAction`. Let's see back in the JS:
`validate()` is defined in `js/mage/form.js` and if there is a `validationUrl` set, it will call `_validate`.

```
_validate : function(){
        new Ajax.Request(this.validationUrl,{
            method: 'post',
            parameters: $(this.formId).serialize(),
            onComplete: this._processValidationResult.bind(this),
            onFailure: this._processFailure.bind(this)
        });
```

Here we can see that the `validateAction` request is called and the `package_theme` parameter is not split. `onComplete` (ajax request complete) will do `_processValidationResult` which will display the error message:

```
$('messages').innerHTML = response.message;
```

#### But why not everyone complains about this or why the error is not always visible ?

It all depends on the server speed. As you can see, there is no waiting before setLocation is called in the setSettings function.
So if the server is fast enough, the redirect will be done before validation is finnished and result parsed.

#### Convince yourself

Take any Magento 1.x instance you have (latest now is 1.9.3.1, I've tested on 1.7.0.2 and 1.9.3.1), go to `CMS/Widgets > Add new widget instance`, use Chrome inspect element, go to Network tab, check Preserve logs, select XHR requests, click Continue and check the validation ajax response.
The error will be there and now we know!

[image]

Comment: any chance to fix it?